# transfer learning of Inception v3 returns the same predictions

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification

I have tried to customize inception to classify. I used the cat, dog, human and other to classify cat, dog, human ( collection of family photos) and other (mostly natural scenes) I have about 2000 dog, 1000 cat, 7000 human and 3000 images split 80:20 among the train and validate. The essence of model is as below. When I train the training accuracy is close to 97% and validation accuracy is ~90%.

```
    import os

    from tensorflow.keras import layers
    from tensorflow.keras import Model
    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
      
    from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
    
    local_weights_file = 'C:/users/sethr/education/Healthcare/imagedetect/modelimageadvance /inception_v3_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5'
    
    pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (150, 150,3), include_top = False, weights =  `enter code here`local_weights_file)
    for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
        layer.trainable = False 
    # pre_trained_model.summary()
    last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer('mixed7')
    #print('last layer output shape: ', last_layer.output_shape)
    last_output = last_layer.output
    # Flatten the output layer to 1 dimension
    x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(last_output)
    # Add a fully connected layer with 1,024 hidden units and ReLU activation
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
    # Add a dropout rate of 0.2
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(x)                  
    # Add a final sigmoid layer for classification
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)           
    
    model = Model(pre_trained_model.input, x)
    
    model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.0001), loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    
    history = model.fit(train_generator,validation_data = validation_generator,steps_per_epoch = 20,epochs = 20,validation_steps = 25,verbose = 2)
    model.save("dcho.rp5")
    ___________________
    
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import glob
    from keras.preprocessing import image
    import matplotlib.image as mpimg
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    labels= ["cat","dog","human","other"]
    path='C:/Users/sethr/education/Healthcare/imagedetect/images/*.jpg'
    for fim in glob.glob(path):
    
      # predicting images
      img=image.load_img(fim, target_size=(150, 150))
      
      x=image.img_to_array(img)
      x=np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
      images = np.vstack([x])
      plt.figure()
      plt.imshow(img)
      plt.show()
      classes = model.predict(images,batch_size=10)

________________________________________________________

_______________________________________________________


# All images will be rescaled by 1./255.
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )
test_datagen  = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )

# --------------------
# Flow training images in batches of 20 using train_datagen generator
# -------------------- 
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                    batch_size=20,
                                                    shuffle='True',
                                                    class_mode='categorical', 
                                                    target_size=(150, 150)) 
# --------------------

    # Flow validation images in batches of 20 using test_datagen generator
    # --------------------
    validation_generator =  test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir,
                                                             target_size = (150, 150),
                                                             batch_size=20,
                                                             class_mode='categorical',
                                                             shuffle='True',
                                                             )

_______________________________________________________________
```

The problem is it is returning always human as prediction.. I played around with Adam, Adjusted learning rate but still the prediction remains the same. Any insight.

Comment: Did you do the same preprocessing as the training data?

Comment: can you include `train_generator`, `validation_data` and everything that's missing?

Comment: train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )
test_datagen  = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255 ) 
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                    batch_size=20,
                                                    shuffle='True',
                                                    class_mode='categorical', 
                                                    target_size=(150, 150))

Comment: validation_generator =  test_datagen.flow_from_directory(validation_dir,
                                                         target_size = (150, 150),
                                                         batch_size=20,
                                                         class_mode='categorical',
                                                         shuffle='True',
                                                         )

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I edited the code as such to include the train and validation code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have not done the rescaling part when you predicting images.

You are doing rescaling only for training and validation

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )
test_datagen  = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1.0/255. )
# Note - this test_datagen used for validation
```

In order to get correct predictions, we should do the same preprocessing steps as we did for training and validation. So you need to rescale the image.

You can rescale the image by using this code

```
x = x* 1.0/255.0
```

So the correct predicting image part is shown below.

```
    for fim in glob.glob(path):
    
      # predicting images
      img=image.load_img(fim, target_size=(150, 150))
      
      x=image.img_to_array(img)
      x=np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

      # Add this line
      x = x* 1.0/255.0

      images = np.vstack([x])
      plt.figure()
      plt.imshow(img)
      plt.show()
      classes = model.predict(images,batch_size=10)
```